# Replace specific character only when within a boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

Replace specific character only when within a boundary.

For example replace html entity only when enclosed inside single quotes.

Input:

```
<i>Hello</i> '<i>How are you</i>'
```

Output:

```
<i>Hello</i> '&lt;i&gt;How are you&lt;/i&gt;'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a callback:

```
var s = "<i>Hello</i> '<i>How are you</i>'";

var r = s.replace(/('[^']+')/g, function($0, $1) {
                     return $1.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'); });
//=> <i>Hello</i> '&lt;i&gt;How are you&lt;/i&gt';
```

Comment: Try it with `<i title="a'b">Hello</i> '<i>How are you</i>'`. [HTML can't be parsed with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630).

Comment: This is just a string and I am trying to do same as StackOverflow does.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use several regular expressions, first capture the text within single quotes, and then replace all occurrences of your character.

```
var input = "<i>Hello</i> '<i>How are you</i>'";

var quoted = input.match(/'.*'/)[0];

var output = quoted.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;");

// output == "<i>Hello</i> '&lt;i&gt;How are you&lt;/i&gt;'"
```